# Convert varchar to integer from substring

Tags: sql-server, integer, varchar

using Microsoft SQL Server 2019

So I have parsed out several columns from a large text field and will need to use the parsed data as a multiplier to other fields
here is a single parsed column mostly for context

```
SUBSTRING(curv.curv_data, 
          CHARINDEX('PctUsage', curv.curv_data, CHARINDEX('||1', curv.curv_data)) + 9, 
          (CHARINDEX(')())', curv.curv_data, CHARINDEX('PctUsage', curv.curv_data, CHARINDEX('||2', curv.curv_data))) - 9) - CHARINDEX('PctUsage', curv.curv_data, CHARINDEX('||1', curv.curv_data) + 9)) PctUsage1
```

Here is the output.

| PctUsage1 |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 3.5 |
| 0.5 |
| 6.5 |
| 5 |
| 9 |
| 1 |
| 1.3 |
| 1.5 |
| 25. |
| 4 |
| 0.0 |
| 1.2 |

so given there are 0s and 0.5 I am having a hard time turning this column into something useful. the end result I would like is to turn these into usable percentages for example 5 turns into .05 and so on.

I am going to be using the SQL above in a sub-select that will then be used as a multiplier for my working hours field here is an example of my multiplier field

| Working_hours |
| --- |
| 51.600006 |
| 0.000000 |
| 20.799993 |
| 8.399999 |
| 28.799999 |
| 86.027731 |
| 5.199999 |

This is the line I would like to be able to use

```
PctUsage1*Working_hours curved_hours,
```

So working_hours is an Integer already but Pctusage1 is a varchar

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: If you need decimal places you want to use a decimal datatype, not int. You can easily turn your results into your desired output by simply dividing by 100.0. Notice the decimal point there, it is important.

Comment: FYI you are using SQL Server, *not* SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). SSMS is just an IDE for use with SQL Server. It's like saying you're using Visual Studio when being asked what language you are coding in.

Comment: I am very open to dividing the results into 100 for that, my problem is turning the varchar that it currently is into something that can be divided, if you have any suggestions I am all ears(and eyes) Thank you for the response!

Comment: In regards to turning them into percentages, I would personally keep them as decimal values. 5% as a numerical value *is* `0.05` and any good presentation layer will display a value like `0.05` when given a format style of something like `"0%"` will display that value as `5%`.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you, that will be helpful moving forward. is there an easy way to tell what version of SQL server I am running?

Comment: Use `@@VERSION`. Running either `PRINT @@VERSION;` or `SELECT @@VERSION;` will give you the full details of the version you're using, down the the build and type of operating system it's on.

Comment: @larnu Adding more context to this. It will be being used as a sub select so i need to use the results to calculate my final output. these numbers as they are are not helpful to me until i can use them as a multiplier within my SQL statement. I hope that makes sense. Thank you for the input!

Comment: Sounds like we're missing some steps then, @Dave . Perhaps you could [edit] your question accordingly? Some consumable sample data (not an image) and the expected results will greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i think i have a solution, sorry for any of the trouble you guys have taken i guess writing out my problem really helped me work through it. i used a case statement with try_cast that helped filter out the different problems i was having with using only one solution. the last problem with this is making sure my multiplier is correct for that i had to use CHARINDEX with an imbedded case statement

```
case when try_cast(PctUsage1 as int) is null then case when CHARINDEX('.',PctUsage1) = 3 then cast(replace(PctUsage1, '.','') as Decimal(5,2))/100 when CHARINDEX('.',PctUsage1) = 2 then cast(replace(PctUsage1, '.','') as Decimal(5,2))/1000 end else try_cast(PctUsage1 as decimal(5,2))/100 end PctUsage1_converted,
```